# Printing Multiple files in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My requirement is that when a user selects more than one pdf and hit the print button then all the pdf gets printed.These pdfs are residing inside a folder with a format(i.e having particular index order) to access it.how we can achieve it?

Comment: What makes you think you can control a printer running on a client.

Comment: it's not about accessing client printer.The thing is when client select more than one doc and hit the print button then a printing window appears similar to as when we use window.print().

Comment: A server has absolutely no control over any files or printers on a client or what gets printed when or in what order.

Comment: Again i guess u misunderstood the scenarios..It's just like lets say u select 3-4 mails from your inbox and u have provided a button inside inbox.After selecting mails and on clicking of print button a window gets open up like what we have when we print a doc.I hope it make sense..

Comment: No its you who is not understanding. Its the browser that controls it, not you.